# Information of things inside a black hole

Tags: black-holes, information

**Can we get the information of things that are gone in black hole?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has the black hole information loss paradox been settled?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3521/)

Comment: Has the experiment be done? No. So we don't know. Very simple.